# Make a PUT/POST request in JSON-Server Android Java

Tags: java, android, post, put, json-server

I created a [JSON-Server](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/json-server-for-frontend-development/).
The server contains this:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Pankaj",
      "salary": "10000"
    },
    {
      "name": "David",
      "salary": "5000",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been trying to make a POST or a PUT request to that server without any luck.

My code is in a `public class InfoLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String>`. My code works correctly if I do a GET request.
Code is shown here:

```
try{
            url = new URL(this.url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();
            OutputStreamWriter out = null;

            try{
                out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("InfoLoader", "can't get OutputStream", e);
            }


            String jsonInputString = "{\"name\": \"Lisa\",\"salary\": \"2000\"}";


            out.write(jsonInputString);
            out.close();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("InfoLoader", "Fallo HTTP", e);
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
```

I'm able to connect and do a GET request without problem. So I know that I'm able to connect to the server. No, the server is NOT in a read only mode.

I'm using Android Studio, Java.

How do I make a POST or PUT request correctly?
I'm not sure what should I do differently. I've search online but there isn't a lot of info about this problem. Also, there is this [web](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#getting-started:%7E:text=Also%20when%20doing%20requests%2C%20it%27s%20good%20to%20know%20that%3A) that gives example of how to do it in a different way. Maybe it could help you help me.

I don't really think it's a Server problem. This JSON-Server shows your request, and i was able to make appear a "PUT" request, but it was ignored.

Thank you in advance for your help.